# Purposefully asking possible community wiki questions?

Tags: discussion

Is there any proscription that I'm not aware of that says you shouldn't ask questions you know have a good chance of being a community wiki, or that you already know the answer to?

I'm trying to come up with questions that I think would be great general knowledge references, but wasn't sure if that was a "frowned upon" practice.

Comment: I also would like to know if this is a good thing or not. I've also been asking questions that I thought would be "canonical".

Comment: You can answer your own questions as long the question is clear enough and it's treated as any other question.

Comment: "[… it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)"

Comment: Personally I think you should ask questions that you are interested in.  If you later find out the answer, then it is ok to post an answer to your question.

Comment: @PatrickHoefler, why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Mew Why not sharing knowledge?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, if people wanted that knowledge, they would ask for it themselves.

Comment: @Mew One doesn't always think if all possible questions. Also, posting a Q&A can allow the poster to write down  knowledge fresh in his mind before he forgets the details.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, good points, i'm convinced.

Answer (score 5):

Let me start with your second question:

[Is it OK to ask questions you already know the answer to?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

> … it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is
>   explicitly encouraged.

With community wikis, [things are less clear-cut](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” […] Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration. That’s when community wiki shines.

And as a [general rule of thumb](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) (from the same source as above):

> A site should never have more than one community wiki question for every hundred questions.